# Apache NiFi/Cassandra - PutCassandraRecord failed to convert into a Record object

Tags: cassandra, apache-nifi

I am trying to use NiFi's PutCassandraRecord processor to insert some JSON records into a Cassandra DB. 
I'm trying to insert a timestamp type into Cassandra, but NiFi is complaining about a NumberFormatException for input string "2019-02-02T08:00:00.000"

The cassandra data type for said timestamp field is (ts timestamp)
I'm using an Avro schema with: 
{ "name": "ts", "type": {"type": "long", "logicalType": "timestamp-millis"}}

```
{
  "name": "app.records",
  "type": "record",
  "fields": [
    { "name": "ts", "type": {"type": "long", "logicalType": "timestamp-millis"}},
    { "name": "app_name", "type": "string" },
```

NiFi logs show that it's able to parse the JSON object but couldn't convert it to a record...

```
2019-05-13 21:13:04,036 ERROR [Timer-Driven Process Thread-2] o.a.n.p.cassandra.PutCassandraRecord PutCassandraRecord[id=ecb33d77-cc4a-17f5-23a8-e002e1777a1c] Unable to write the records into Cassandra table due to org.apache.nifi.serialization.MalformedRecordException: Successfully parsed a JSON object from input but failed to convert into a Record object with the given schema: org.apache.nifi.serialization.MalformedRecordException: Successfully parsed a JSON object from input but failed to convert into a Record object with the given schema
org.apache.nifi.serialization.MalformedRecordException: Successfully parsed a JSON object from input but failed to convert into a Record object with the given schema
        at org.apache.nifi.json.AbstractJsonRowRecordReader.nextRecord(AbstractJsonRowRecordReader.java:98)
        at org.apache.nifi.serialization.RecordReader.nextRecord(RecordReader.java:50)
        at org.apache.nifi.processors.cassandra.PutCassandraRecord.onTrigger(PutCassandraRecord.java:151)
        at org.apache.nifi.processor.AbstractProcessor.onTrigger(AbstractProcessor.java:27)
        at org.apache.nifi.controller.StandardProcessorNode.onTrigger(StandardProcessorNode.java:1162)
        at org.apache.nifi.controller.tasks.ConnectableTask.invoke(ConnectableTask.java:209)
        at org.apache.nifi.controller.scheduling.TimerDrivenSchedulingAgent$1.run(TimerDrivenSchedulingAgent.java:117)
        at org.apache.nifi.engine.FlowEngine$2.run(FlowEngine.java:110)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "2019-02-02T08:00:35.473"
        at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
        at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:589)
        at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:631)
        at org.apache.nifi.serialization.record.util.DataTypeUtils.toTimestamp(DataTypeUtils.java:1057)
        at org.apache.nifi.serialization.record.util.DataTypeUtils.convertType(DataTypeUtils.java:156)
        at org.apache.nifi.serialization.record.util.DataTypeUtils.convertType(DataTypeUtils.java:120)
        at org.apache.nifi.json.JsonTreeRowRecordReader.convertField(JsonTreeRowRecordReader.java:170)
        at org.apache.nifi.json.JsonTreeRowRecordReader.convertJsonNodeToRecord(JsonTreeRowRecordReader.java:137)
        at org.apache.nifi.json.JsonTreeRowRecordReader.convertJsonNodeToRecord(JsonTreeRowRecordReader.java:83)
        at org.apache.nifi.json.JsonTreeRowRecordReader.convertJsonNodeToRecord(JsonTreeRowRecordReader.java:74)
        at org.apache.nifi.json.AbstractJsonRowRecordReader.nextRecord(AbstractJsonRowRecordReader.java:93)
        ... 14 common frames omitted
```

The types seem to be all correct.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Which version of NiFi are you using?

Comment: I am using 1.9.2

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're trying to insert timestamp field without specification of the format for the date. The [corresponding code](https://github.com/apache/nifi/blob/master/nifi-commons/nifi-record/src/main/java/org/apache/nifi/serialization/record/util/DataTypeUtils.java#L1057) looks as following:

> If input data is string, then try to get format string for it, and then if the format string is valid formatter, then get date using it. If either format string is not specified, or it's not valid, then NiFi is trying to convert it using `Long.parseLong`.

You need to either perform explicit casting of the corresponding field with something like this:

```
toDate("yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss")
```

Comment: Hi @Alex,
I tried to cast to a datetime using a NiFi ExecuteScript processor, but when I tried to write the flowfile out to an outputstream using:

 def process(self, inputStream, outputStream):
    text = IOUtils.toString(inputStream, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
    obj = json.loads(text)
    fields = obj['fields']
    simpleTime = fields['_time']
    ts = datetime.strptime(strippedTime, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')
    fields['ts'] = ts
    out = json.dumps(fields)

I am getting 

TypeError: datetime.datetime(2019, 2, 2, 8, 0, 35, 473000) is not JSON serializable

Comment: I also tried "out =  json.dumps(fields, indent=4, sort_keys=True, default=str)"
so it can be serialized properly... But I then run into the original issue of not being able to convert to Record

Answer (score 0):

I ended up converting the datetime to an epoch timestamp, and converted that to milliseconds and casted it to a long in order for it to work with my Avro schema.

```
ts = datetime.datetime.strptime(strippedTime, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')
epoch = datetime.datetime(1970,1,1)
timestamp = long((ts-epoch).total_seconds()*1000)
fields['ts'] = timestamp
```

Answer (score 0):

I too faced the same issue and resolved it by giving Timestamp format on JSONTreeReader of PutCassandraRecord processor, In your case it should be
yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS

schema given is correct and worked
{ "name": "ts", "type": {"type": "long", "logicalType": "timestamp-millis"}}